# Can an app dynamically request more permissions than what is given statically?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm setting up permissions for a new app I registered and saw this blurb:

> These are the permissions that this application requests statically.  You may also request user consent-able permissions dynamically through code.

[image]

**Can an app dynamically request more permissions than what is given statically?**

The concern is that this app is developed by a third-party service provider and we don't wish the app to request more permissions that what is listed.  Yes, we understand the user has to consent.  We know a good portion of users will just accept without reading and/or understanding what is being requested.  We wish to restrict the permissions the app can request.

Answer (score 1):

With Azure AD V2, you are not able to restrict the permissions.But users will be asked to consent if new permissions were required, and if the permission is admin consent required, then only the admin can consent. So, basically that will not be a big problem.

At the same time, you can always check the granted permissions in Azure Portal. Click: Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> Search with app name, and you will find the application. You will be able to check the granted permission and the operators.